# API Plataform: Rest resource name + Class does not exists error

Tags: php, symfony, restful-architecture, api-platform.com, hydra-core

I am trying my first steps with Symfony 4 and API Platform to create a real simple API but, I am getting troubles with two points:

1) I don't know/understand why the Resource Name from my Entity is getting the first letter removed + it's adding plural in the end

[image]

[image]

2) When I try the request using Postman I get the error message below:

[image]

I feel that I am really missing some point and extra info... It can't be that complicate...

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: Why is there no namespace?

Comment: @Orange18947 - exactly! the first point was it. Basically I tried to create entities from the database using the "old" command " php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml " but symfony 4 is bundle-less so I ran another command and it was missing the namespaces...

Comment: @Orange18947 - plus, I had to create getter/setters for the entities... after it, all was generated.... Thanks a lot!